# I'm having problem figuring why login is working sometimes but sometimes not with Graph and Firebase

Tags: javascript, graph, apollo, apollo-client

So, I have built this way of auth with firebase and graphql using mongo database, the problem is that everything is working, instead trying to login, its the same way of register but sometimes the method works and some times I get apollo client error, which I don't know why.

Here is my code to auth with Firebase and then check if the user exits and call the method and then the oposite.

```js
import { FirebaseAuth } from "../config/Firebase";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { Notifier } from "../utils";

import { USER_AUTH_ERROR } from "../config/Responders";

const Google = async (Register, Login, dispatch) => {
  var Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const data = await signInWithPopup(FirebaseAuth, Provider);

  try {
    if (data) {
      const user = data.user;
      const creationTime = user.metadata.creationTime;
      const lastSignInTime = user.metadata.lastSignInTime;

      if (creationTime === lastSignInTime) {
        const name = user.displayName.split(" ");
        const firstName = name[0] || "";
        const lastName = name[1] || "";

        const config = {
          variables: {
            createUserInput: {
              Name: firstName,
              Surname: lastName,
              Email: user.email,
              Avatar: user.photoURL || null,
              Uid: user.uid,
            },
          },
        };

        Register(config);
      } 
      
      else {
        const config = {
          variables: {
            uid: user.uid,
          },
        };
        
        Login(config);
      }
    } 
    
    else Notifier(dispatch, USER_AUTH_ERROR, `error`);
  } catch (error) {
    Notifier(dispatch, USER_AUTH_ERROR, `error`);
  }
};

export
 default Google;
```

While here is the place where I manage the functions:

```js
const [Register, { data: registerData }] = useMutation(REGISTER);
  const [Login, { data: loginData }] = useLazyQuery(AUTH);

  const Auther = () => Google(Register, Login, dispatch);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!account.Auth) {
      if (registerData?.hasOwnProperty("UserRegister")) {
        dispatch(Authenticate(registerData.UserRegister));
      }
    }
  }, [registerData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!account.Auth) {
      if (loginData?.hasOwnProperty("UserAuth")) {
        dispatch(Authenticate(loginData.UserAuth));
      }
    }
  }, [loginData]);
```

Here is the error I get:
[image]

Comment: What's the client error you're getting?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I showed the error